# C# High CPU Load when using serial port

Tags: .net

I'm coding a Serial port application and my first problems were solved here at stackoverflow.
The Baud rate is 115200 and the Problem is that through simple usage of the serial port the CPU load is about 12 % on a i7 quad core at 4 GHz. If I'm doing some simple processing on the data the load rises up to about 30-33%. Because I need to run in on a laptop it would be great if someone could get me an advice on how to make this more efficient. 
Thing I've tried:

1. Tried to do the data processing in a workerthread but then he told me the the backgroundworker is operating at full load and cannot do more tasks parallel (freely translated)
2. ReceivedBytesTreshold raised brings next to nothing

Here are parts of the code:

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived_1(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {
            int bytes = serialPort1.BytesToRead;
            byte[] comBuffer = new byte[bytes];
            serialPort1.Read(comBuffer, 0, bytes);
            this.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler<DataEventArgs>(DisplayText), this, new DataEventArgs { Data = comBuffer });
        }
    } 

public class DataEventArgs : EventArgs
        {
            public byte[] Data { get; set; }
        }

private void DisplayText(object sender, DataEventArgs e)
        {
    Array.Reverse(...);
        Array.Reverse(...);
        Array.Reverse(...);
        Array.Reverse(...);
        angle0 = BitConverter.ToSingle(..., 0);
        angle1 = BitConverter.ToSingle(..., 0);
        gyro0 = BitConverter.ToInt16(..., 0);  
    ...
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: 1. You do a lot of unnecessary allocation 2. What does your Array.Reverse(..) do?

Comment: Because on the other side of the serial port is an arm controller and so byte alignment does not match!

Comment: I ment: How much does it do

Comment: 5 arrays of 2 bytes length and 2 arrays of 4 byte length will be reversed!

Comment: How much data is getting sent and how often by whatever you are connected to?

Comment: 38 bytes 250 time a second!

Comment: Just discovered: HTerm (Terminal emulation programm) also uses nearly 40 % CPU. Cannot be truth, perhaps the driver of the usb serial adapter isn't good or anything?!

Comment: You are fire-hosing the UI thread, it is wildly updating the UI at a rate that's about 10 times higher than a human eye can ever observe.  Sure, keeps the processor pretty busy, doesn't actually do anything useful.